# MinGW cannot find inttypes.h

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm trying to follow the OpenGL 3D tutorials as shown here:
http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html

And I've followed the instructions written for building the tutorials, but when I type make config=debug in the OpenGL SDK directory using MinGW's msys program after using the premake function, there is the one compiler error that says "inttypes.h: No such file or directory."

```
    In file included from include/glload/gl_all.hpp:9,
                     from source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:4:
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:731: error: integer constant is too large for "l
    ong" type
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:4322: error: GLuint64' has not been declared
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:4322: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration oftim
    eout' with no type
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:4328: error: GLuint64' has not been declared
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:4328: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration oftim
    eout' with no type
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:4355: error: GLuint64' has not been declared
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:4355: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration ofpar
    ams' with no type
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5273: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of GLu
    int64' with no type
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5273: error: typedefgl::_detail::GLuint64' is
    initialized (use typeof instead)
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5273: error: Proc_glGetImageHandleARB' was not
    declared in this scope
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5273: error: expected,' or ;' before '(' toke
    n
    include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5276: error:GLuint64EXT' has not been declared
```

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5276: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `par
ams' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5287: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5287: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5288: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5288: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5291: error: expected init-declarator before "Ge
tImageHandleARB"
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:5291: error: expected `,' or `;' before "GetImag
eHandleARB"
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7879: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7879: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7880: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7880: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7883: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7883: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7883: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7883: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7884: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7884: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7887: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7887: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7887: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7887: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7887: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7887: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `z'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7888: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7888: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `z'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7891: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `w'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7892: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7892: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7895: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7895: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7896: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7896: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7899: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7899: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7899: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7899: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7900: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7900: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7903: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7903: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7903: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7903: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7903: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7903: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `z'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7904: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7904: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `z'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7907: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `w'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7908: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:7908: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8197: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8197: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `par
ams' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8199: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8199: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `min
PresentTime' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8200: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8200: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `min
PresentTime' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8261: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8261: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `par
ams' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8262: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8262: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `res
ult' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8263: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8263: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `par
ams' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8264: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8264: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `par
ams' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8271: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8271: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `val
ue' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8272: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8272: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8273: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8273: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `val
ue' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8274: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8274: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8401: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8401: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `par
ams' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8404: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8404: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8405: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8405: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8408: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8408: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8408: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8408: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8409: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8409: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8412: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8412: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8412: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8412: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8412: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8412: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `z'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8413: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8413: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `x'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `y'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `z'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8416: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `w'
with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8417: error: expected `,' or `...' before '*' to
ken
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8417: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `GLu
int64EXT' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8443: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8443: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `add
ress' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8447: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8447: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `res
ult' with no type
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8664: error: `GLuint64EXT' has not been declared

include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:8664: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `cap
ture_time' with no type
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:879: error: expected init-declarator before "_funcptr_glG
etImageHandleARB"
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:879: error: expected `,' or `;' before "_funcptr_glGetIma
geHandleARB"
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:4342: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type co
nversion before "GetImageHandleARB"
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:4342: error: expected `,' or `;' before "GetImageHandleAR
B"
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp: In function `void gl::CopyFunctionPointers()':
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:7624: error: `GetImageHandleARB' undeclared (first use th
is function)
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:7624: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only
 once for each function it appears in.)
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:7624: error: `_funcptr_glGetImageHandleARB' undeclared (f
irst use this function)
make: *** [Debug/gl_load_cpp.o] Error 1

</code></pre>

I'm currently using MinGW to compile this, and I have to use both the Windows command prompt and MSYS to get this to work.

Comment: How did you set up your MinGW / MSYS environment, and what command do you use to run the shell environment from where you're building?

Comment: Windows command prompt / MSYS (I'm trying both.) I'm trying to make the Unofficial OpenGL SDK in folder glsdk_0_5_2, and I put that folder in the MinGW folder. I typed "make config=debug" and "make config=release" and both gave errors although I followed the instructions completely.

Comment: My question was really targeting at how *exactly* did you set up / install your MSYS environment. Like, did you use [this installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files)? Also, after installing, how to you *start* the MSYS environment, do you run `msys.bat` from the installation directory? What does `echo $MSYSTEM` say? It should say `MINGW32` (not `MSYS`) in order to be able to use the right GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Use a more updated version, download one of the packages here:

[MinGW builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/)

Wichever stuff you use to compile (makefile, cmake, any IDE), you have to let it know where the C/C++ compiler is.

I do that by setting up environment variables (it's more easy than it seems) with a script so that you do not pollute the "global environment":

here's the batch file that allows you to use command line commands like "g++ -bla"

```
set "PATH=D:/MinGWBuilds/mingw32/bin;C:/Windows/System32;"
set "CC=D:/MinGWBuilds/mingw32/bin/gcc"
set "CXX=D:/MinGWBuilds/mingw32/bin/g++"
set DXSDK_DIR="D:/MinGWBuilds/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/ddkv"

cd /d "%~dp0"
cmd.exe
```

You just have to launch your ide from console (easy to do, instead of calling "cmd.exe" you could as well call "CodeBlocks.exe" or any other Ide/text editor/script runner, you just need to add its path to PATH).

You have of course to add yourself the path to missing programs like python/lua interpreter etc. Don't blame me for using Env Variables and command prompt, it is really making your life easier once you got the script with all things you need. In example I use that in conjunction with CMake to do almost everything (cross compiling for Win,Mac,Linux,Android etc using various compiler versions because I maintaining a library, I also generate VS project files while developing so I could use nice completion features of VS also when compiling for Linux :D)

Note that I no longer use MSYS nor MSYS2. I just use makefiles generated by Cmake. and the make executable inside `mingw32/bin` folder (mingw32-make.exe)

Oh, and remember that you need to enable c++11 with the following compile flag

`-std=c++11`

after that you can include `cinttypes` freely.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using the wrong environment / GCC compiler. In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759901/mingw-cannot-find-inttypes-h#comment43936488_27759972) you say you're using MSYS' GCC, which indeed is stuck at version 3.4.4, and for some reason lacks `inttypes.h`. However, there's also *MinGW* GCC that comes with MinGW / MSYS, and that is at version 4.8.1, and comes with `inttypes.h`.

Answer (score 1):

`inttypes.h` is a POSIX and C99 header, not C++03, so it's not going to be available to a C++03 implementation on Windows.

However, since this is 2015, you can use C++11 and its [`cinttypes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes) header which is the modern, C++, standardised version of `inttypes.h`.

Comment: I just tried to replace all instances of inttypes.h with cinttypes in the file _int_gl_exts.h file, but the error still happens. Did I not install the glSDK correctly? I put the folder containing all of the files within the SDK into the MinGW folder.

Comment: The GL SDK is irrelevant; as I said, `inttypes.h` is POSIX and `cinttypes` is C++11. Are you using C++11?

Comment: As it turns out, the g++ compiler on MSYS is stuck at 3.4.4 and I can't figure out how to update it since mingw-get.exe seems to crash when I do.